# Chrome Storage API to set state in useState

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

How can I use the Chrome Storage API to set the initial state of my react app?

From my understanding `chrome.storage.sync.get()` is callback based and has no return value.

I've tried:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("tabs", (result) => {
  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(result.tabs);
});
```

But this gives an error that the useState declaration cannot be nested inside a function.

I've also tried:

```
var init_tabs = null;
chrome.storage.sync.get("tabs", (result) => {
  init_tabs = result.tabs
});
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(init_tabs);
```

But this also seems to not have an impact.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

### Edit

You can use `new Promise()` to guarantee a response.

```
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(async () => {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("tabs", (result) => {
      resolve(result.tabs);
    });
  });

  return await promise;
});
```

Comment: The second example fails to work because the get call is async. Why not wrap the get call inside a promise? And use `async await` on the promise. This way, you are guaranteed to have the get value executed before moving to the initialization of initial state.

Comment: @codemax THANK YOU! I've learned something new and seemed to have fixed the issue that was blocking me for a couple of days. Let me know if my edit to the question is a good approach.

Comment: Yes that looks good. Maybe you can extract the promise out of the `useState` into its own line, so that you can handle the `get` call error and create a fallback value.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I am doing. I also handle the reject case. Never promisified values before so it is nice to see why it is useful.

Comment: Okay great. Good that you learnt smth new ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

```
var init_tabs = null;
chrome.storage.sync.get("tabs", (result) => {
  init_tabs = result.tabs
});
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(init_tabs);
```

This doesn't work for a few reasons:

1. State from the `useState` react hook is only ever initialized once.
2. `init_tabs` would be reset each render cycle and the `chrome.storage.sync.get` invoked each cycle, but `init_tabs = result.tabs` would be fruitless as it would likey occur in some *later* render cycle.

## Solution

I'm not exactly sure what your `tabs` state object shape is, and your promise-based state initializer looks like it could work, but a more standard react way (i.e. idiomatic) to load state is to do the data "fetch/load" in an `useEffect` hook when the component mounts. It uses a lot of the same logic from your edit, but is more conventional and doesn't require being wrapped up in a promise.

```
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState(/* ... some initial state ... */);

useEffect(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("tabs", (result) => {
    setTabs(result.tabs);
  });
}, []); // <-- empty dependency array to run effect callback once "onMount"
```

From here it is up to you how to best handle rendering your UI while the `tabs` state is populated.

Comment: This is what I was after, thank you for posting! I was initially doing this but getting some unrelated errors which threw me off. Your post cleared all my confusing and more importantly now my app works as expected.